# How to iterate over a list and do a calculation based on cell values?

Tags: excel

I have a list of elements like:

```
item name , date 1 , date 2
abc , 10/03/2020 , 16/03/2020
abc , 11/03/2020 , 15/03/2020
abc , 08/03/2020 , 15/03/2020
def , 07/03/2020 , 11/03/2020
xyz , 10/03/2020 , 11/03/2020
xyz , 12/03/2020 , 14/03/2020
```

My objective here is to have the average of difference between `date 2` and `date 1` for each `item name`.

For example, for `abc` it should be `5.67`.

`AVERAGE(16/03/2020-10/03/2020;15/03/2020-11/03/2020;15/03/2020-08/03/2020) = 5.67`

I need to use `VLOOKUP` function?

Thank for help.

Comment: How it should be 5.67? Can you explain? Do you tried anything?

Comment: I updated my question with a more detail example. I can do it with VBA, but I need to do it without it. So I need to iterate over the list and do the average for each item.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *Formula simplified*

If you have Excel/O365 with dynamic arrays, you can use the following formulas:

```
F2: =UNIQUE(A2:A7)
G2: =AVERAGE(IF(F2=A2:A7,C2:C7-B2:B7))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, the formula may need to be entered with `CSE` : by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, and you will need a different method of constructing the list of item_names, if you want to output the results as I show.*

[image]

or you could use Power Query.